# How do I use jade(pug)'s "if statement" inside a css block?

Tags: pug, pugjs

Say I have a jade template like:

```
style.
  .someclass1{
    font-size:10px;
  }
  .someclass2{
    font-size:10px;
  }
  .someclass3{
    font-size:10px;
  }
  .someclass4{
    font-size:10px;
  }
  .someclass5{
    font-size:10px;
  }
```

And I want to make `.someclass3` with different results from different options when rendering the jade template.

Something like:

```
style.
  .someclass1{
    font-size:10px;
  }
  .someclass2{
    font-size:10px;
  }
  if(options.key1=='a')
    .someclass3{
      font-size:10px;
    }
  else
    .someclass3{
      font-size:8px;
    }
  .someclass4{
    font-size:10px;
  }
  .someclass5{
    font-size:10px;
  }
```

It's not working.

I have to break the style tag into two and do something like this:

```
style.
  .someclass1{
    font-size:10px;
  }
  .someclass2{
    font-size:10px;
  }
if(options.key1=='a')
  style.
    .someclass3{
      font-size:10px;
    }
else
  style.
    .someclass3{
      font-size:8px;
    }
style.
  .someclass4{
    font-size:10px;
  }
  .someclass5{
    font-size:10px;
  }
```

This will result in a 3-style tags HTML, which is actually only needing one.

Anyone has good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this.  Instead of putting the `.` immediately after the `style` tag (which tells pug that the entire block is plain text), you can put the `.` before each block of plain text.  eg.

```
style
  .
    .someclass1{
      font-size:10px;
    }
    .someclass2{
      font-size:10px;
    }
  if options.key1=='a'
    .
      .someclass3{
        font-size:10px;
      }
  else
    .
      .someclass3{
        font-size:8px;
      }
  .
    .someclass4{
      font-size:10px;
    }
    .someclass5{
      font-size:10px;
    }
```

Comment: AWESOME, thanks! Is that working for jade or only for pug?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd highly recommend you upgrade to pug.

Comment: Just that it is actively maintained.  It will get all the bug fixes, security fixes, new features and documentation.  If you find a bug in jade all you'll get is "Upgrade to pug and let us know if you still have the same problem".

Comment: Just confirmed, not working with jade (only with pug)  :( Sad!